# How do I wrap all separately loaded jQuery snippets into a $(document).ready() call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple scripts tags loading to the DOM. But I would instead like to wrap all of them like so:

```js
$(document).ready( () => {
  // load script1.js
  // load script2.js
  // load script3.js
  // etc.
});
```

This way I could avoid funky scoping issues if each individually loaded file had a `$(document).ready()` function.

I am trying to use functions defined in the previous script tags within `$(document).ready( // use functions in here)` without crowding the global namespace.

If more information is needed, I will be happy to provide it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you asking about how to load individual scripts, or run code from those individual scripts in the exact same callback? The latter you cannot do as the code is in different files. Though you could request the codes using ajax and `eval` them but wouldn't suggest that.

Answer (score 0):

The `$(document).ready()` is a global function. It is called only once if the complete DOM is ready. This includes all script tags. So you can do all that things in one function.

See the jquery docs too. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

For example:

```
$(document).ready (function () {
    // Init of script1.js
    // Init of script2.js
})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: So I have multiple *.js files with function definitions in them, and I want to make them all work within the one file I have that calls `$(document).ready()`. But the function calls are undefined so I figured it was a scoping issue. Is an efficient way to pass the other scripts to the file that calls `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: You have to define your  `$(document).ready()` after all `<script ...></script>` tags or in the html file directly. If you have further questions please post an example of your code.